# Twig White page instead of fatal error

Tags: php, twig, fatal-error

I'm using Twig which is giving a white page rather than a fatal error. I know this depends on the error reporting settings, but I have to explicity set this as E_ALL for it to work.

I have an error_handler() function and I've set this to handle both fatal and standard (i.e. undefined variable/index) errors. And this works great.

I had to set the error_reporting value to E_PARSE so that the error handler won't show the error, and it be outputted to the browser. But when it comes to using Twig, unless I explicitly set error reporting as E_ALL, it just returns a blank page, and this is no good.

I want my error handler to be able to handle these errors. For example, if an exception occurs outside of Twig, the error handler works. Otherwise, it just doesn't.

My question is, is there someway to force Twig to use the error handler I want (such as a value to pass), while keeping the current settings?

Here is an example file:

```
<?php

require PANTHER_ROOT.'include/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';

// Register Twig autoloader
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// Make sure PHP reports no errors apart from parse errors (this is handled by the error handler)
error_reporting(E_PARSE);

// Sort out error handling stuff ...
register_shutdown_function('error_handler');
set_error_handler('error_handler');

function error_handler($errno = 0, $errstr = 'Error', $errfile = 'unknown', $errline = 0)
{
    // do something
}

function load_template($tpl_file)
{
    global $tpl_manager, $style_root;
    if (file_exists($style_root.$tpl_file))
        $tpl_file = $tpl_manager->loadTemplate('@style/'.$tpl_file);
    else
        $tpl_file = $tpl_manager->loadTemplate('@core/'.$tpl_file);

    return $tpl_file;
}

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('include/templates');

$style_rot = 'something';
$loader->addPath('include/templates/', 'core');
$loader->addPath($style_root, 'style');

$tpl_manager = new Twig_Environment($loader);


// then, in a seperate file:

$tpl_file = load_template('header.tpl');
$tpl_file->render(
    array(
        // stuff
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig uses exceptions when something fails, not PHP errors. And you don't catch exceptions in your code. This is why you get a blank page: uncaught exceptions are reported as fatal errors by PHP, and you don't display them when setting the error_reporting to E_PARSE only.

The solution is to catch exceptions too, using `set_exception_handler` or a `try/catch` around the calls to Twig.